# How to access this array containing objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The table filed name is called metadata, and within the metadata contained an array of objects such as

```
[{"title":"Type","value":"Hard Drive (HDD)"},{"title":"Condition","value":"Used"}]
```

How do I access it using PHP/Laravel. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need `json_decode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode it, with **[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** php function :

```
$x = '[{"title":"Type","value":"Hard Drive (HDD)"},{"title":"Condition","value":"Used"}]';
$y = json_decode($x, true);
print_r($y);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
     (
         [title] => Type
         [value] => Hard Drive (HDD)
     )

 [1] => Array
     (
         [title] => Condition
         [value] => Used
     )
)
```

Now you can access the value with foreach loop as :

```
foreach($y as $key => $val) {
      echo "Title : " . $val['title'] . $val['value'] ;
 }
```

Above code tested **[here](https://rextester.com/TKPC64333)**

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is a JSON string. So you first have to `decode` it to a PHP array with the function [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). After that you can access it easily.

Try this out:

```php
$json = '[{"title":"Type","value":"Hard Drive (HDD)"},{"title":"Condition","value":"Used"}]';
$assoc_array = json_decode($json, true); // second parameter is true to get an associative array
echo $assoc_array[0]['title'];
```